# Darboux's theorem with open interval

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:(0, 3) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $(0, 3)$. Assume that $f'(1) = 4$ and that $f'(2) = 6.$
>
> Show that there exists a $c \in (1, 2)$ s.t $f'(c) = 5.$
>
> Also you cannot apply Bolzano's theorem, since $f'(x)$ may not be continuous.
>
> Tip: $g(x) = f(x) -5x$.

So approaching this the following way:

Let $g(x) = f(x) -5x$

then $g'(x) = f'(x) -5$

so we have that  $g'(1) = -1$ and $g'(2) = 1$.

But how do we continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the proof of Rolle's Theorem: Note that $g$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ as it is differentiable.

Since $g'(1)<0<g'(2)$, then $g$ does not attain its minimum on $[1,2]$ on neither $1$ nor $2$, so in fact it attains its minimum on some $y\in (1,2)$.

What can you conclude about $g'(y)$?

**Sketch of the remainder**: $g$ is differentiable at $y$. If we had $g'(y)>0$, then for some $t\in(1,y)$ with $t$ very close to $y$, we'd have $0<g'(y)\sim\frac{g(y)-g(t)}{y-t}$, so $g(t)<g(y)$, which contradicts $y$ being a point of minimum. Similarly, we can't have $g'(y)>0$. So $g'(y)=0$, implying $f'(y)=5$.

Comment: Rolle's theorem states that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $\exists c \in (a, b)$ s.t $f'(c) = 0$. How does it help us here?

Comment: @Daniel I didn't say "use Rolle's Theorem". I said "**follow the proof** of Rolle's Theorem".

Comment: If I remember correctly in order to prove Rolle's theorem we had to use the Mean Value Theorem also. Which part of the proof are you referring to?

Comment: @Daniel. I see. Usually the Mean Value Theorem is obtained as a consequence of Rolle's. Let me expand the answer.

Comment: @Daniel And I just noticed I forgot a prime. I wanted "$g'(y)$". Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the update! So let me try to see if I understand what's happening here. Since $g$ is continuous on $[1, 2]$ by the Extreme value theorem we have that $g$ achieves a minimum and a maximum on $[1, 2]$. Since $g'(1) < 0$ and $g'(2) > 0$ we have that the minimum/maximum has to be some $c \in [1, 2]$ which leads us to $c = 0$. So two questions still... Does it matter if the point $c = 0$ is a maximum or a minimum and what's the idea behind finding the max/min in this case? I'm not sure i would saw this from the problem initially.

Comment: @Daniel Since $g'(1)<0$ then the function $g$ "looks decreasing" around $1$ (basically the same argument in the sketch: For $t$ larger than but close to $1$, $0>g'(1)\sim\frac{g(t)-g(1)}{t-1}$.) So think of the graph of $g$: it "points downward" to the middle of the interval $(1,2)$. That is why we look at the minimum (the function $g$ could still attain the maximum only at $x=1$ or $x=2$, so this is not good; that is why we look at minimum). This point $y$ of minimum is not $1$ nor $2$, by the argument above [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Then at least geometrically it should be clear that the derivative at an interior point of minimum is zero: the tangent line is horizontal, so the slope $g'(y)$ is zero! Formally, look at left and right derivatives (this is why the point of minimum needs to be interior, so we have both sides): $g'(y)=g'_+(y)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{g(y+h)-g(y)}{h}\geq 0$, because the numerator and denominator are $>0$ inside the limit. Similarly, $g'(y)=g'_-(y)\leq 0$.